# Image filling a button WP8 Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have the following image within a button, 
As you can see from the screenshot though the button is larger than the image. If I try to reduce the size of the button the image is reduced aswell. How do make the image fill the button with no blanks?

[image]

This is my xaml code

```
    <Button x:Name="Settings" Margin="344,161,0,268" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Click="Settings_Click">
        <Image Source="Assets/wrench.jpg" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="74.487" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="0.63"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Button>
```

----EDIT
My new code as per your suggestions is this, i removed the rotation aswell as it was set by mistake, it is closer now to the full button but not yet

```
    <Button x:Name="Settings" Padding="0" Margin="344,161,0,273" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Click="Settings_Click">
        <Image Source="Assets/wrench.jpg" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="True" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        </Image>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Have you tried with Width and Height set to auto?

Comment: Try setting the `Padding` of the button to 0

Comment: Try removing the harcoded width (`Width="74.487"`) of your image and set `Stretch` to `Fill`.

Comment: You have to override default style of button to fulfill your requirment.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Please explain more in an answer as I do not understand what exactly to do

Comment: This is actually an intended feature of the WP8 button, in order for detecting button clicks even when the user misses the button slightly. Its just something to be aware of, and the accepted answer will get you pass that default design

Comment: I had to use Padding=-10 for the Button to remove the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- set your Image width and height properties
- add Stretch="Fill" to your Image
- remove default padding from Padding (set to 0)

Other solution is to add Tap event to event and remove button.

If you want to handle Tap instead of Click you must get to know that second parameter in Click event handler is type of `RoutedEventArgs`, and in Tap event handler is type of `GestureEventArgs`.

Comment: by set image width and height properties what do you mean?
set them to what?

Comment: To set them to value which you want to Image have

Comment: It does not make any difference, If I set it the same as the button then the image goes outside of the buttons boundaries

Comment: If in the tap handler I call the function that I called on the button click handler, and remove the button, will it work as a "click"?

Comment: Exactly, just look what I have add to my answer.

Comment: I only want for navigation so I will not use event handlers in this case